# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to use all functions of SQS with Elastic Beanstalk? I mean, in the [desctiption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html) they say that web tiers can send messages to worker tiers via SQS. But can web tiers also receive messages from SQS, or lets say, can web tiers use a native SQS-API?

Comment: Elastic beanstalk is a service to deploy your infrastructure, Whether or not to produce/consume messages to/from SQS depends on what is running on that infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the SQS SDK in your code, and have an SQS queue in your account. You should be able to send a message or poll the queue. Elastic Beanstalk just manages the deployment of AWS resources, which are also visible on the console. For eg: you should be able to view the EC2 instances Beanstalk creates.